# Linq TotalCount of "Grandchildren" with null checks and property filters

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

Give the following classes:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("CustomerKey = {CustomerKey}")]
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Orders = new List<Order>();
    }
    public int CustomerKey { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("OrderKey = {OrderKey}, OrderDateOffset='{OrderDateOffset}'")]
public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        this.OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
    }
    public int OrderKey { get; set; }
    public Customer ParentCustomer { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset OrderDateOffset { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("OrderDetailKey='{OrderDetailKey}', ProductKey='{ProductKey}', Quantity='{Quantity}', UnitPrice='{UnitPrice}, BackOrdered='{BackOrdered}'")]
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int OrderDetailKey { get; set; }
    public Order ParentOrder { get; set; }
    public int ProductKey { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public Decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public bool BackOrdered { get; set; }
}
```

Given the following hydration:

```
            ICollection<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

            Customer customerOne = new Customer() { CustomerKey = 11111 };
            /**/
            Order orderOne = null;
            customerOne.Orders.Add(orderOne);/* note, the item added to the collection is null) */
            /**/
            Order orderTwo = new Order() { OrderKey = 22222, OrderDateOffset = DateTimeOffset.Now };
            orderTwo.OrderDetails = null;/* Note, the child collection is null */
            customerOne.Orders.Add(orderTwo);
            /**/
            Order orderThree = new Order() { OrderKey = 22223, OrderDateOffset = DateTimeOffset.Now };
            orderThree.OrderDetails.Add(null); /* note, the item added to the collection is null) */
            customerOne.Orders.Add(orderThree);
            /**/
            Order orderFour = new Order() { OrderKey = 22221, OrderDateOffset = DateTimeOffset.Now };
            orderFour.OrderDetails.Add(new OrderDetail() { OrderDetailKey = 33333, ProductKey = 11, Quantity = 1, UnitPrice = 1M, BackOrdered = false });
            orderFour.OrderDetails.Add(new OrderDetail() { OrderDetailKey = 33334, ProductKey = 12, Quantity = 2, UnitPrice = 2M, BackOrdered = false });
            orderFour.OrderDetails.Add(new OrderDetail() { OrderDetailKey = 33335, ProductKey = 13, Quantity = 3, UnitPrice = 3M, BackOrdered = true });
            customerOne.Orders.Add(orderFour);

            customers.Add(customerOne);
            customers.Add(null);/* note, the item added to the collection is null) */
```

I'm trying to get a total count of all back-ordered OrderDetail(s).

My pre-linq code :

```
            int totalBackOrderedCount = 0;
            if (null != customers)
            {
                foreach (Customer cust in customers)
                {
                    if (null != cust)
                    {
                        if (null != cust.Orders)
                        {
                            foreach (Order ord in cust.Orders)
                            {
                                if (null != ord)
                                {
                                    if (null != ord.OrderDetails)
                                    {
                                        foreach (OrderDetail ordDet in ord.OrderDetails)
                                        {
                                            if (null != ordDet)
                                            {
                                                if (ordDet.BackOrdered)
                                                {
                                                    totalBackOrderedCount++;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine("ordDet was null, good thing I coded for it");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("ord.OrderDetails was null, good thing I coded for it");
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("ord was null, good thing I coded for it");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("cust was null, good thing I coded for it");
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("totalBackOrderedCount={0}", totalBackOrderedCount);
```

My attempt(s) at a linq alternative:

```
            int linqyTotalBackOrderedCountOne =
               (
                 from cust in customers
                 from ord in (cust.Orders ?? Enumerable.Empty<Order>()).DefaultIfEmpty()
                 from ordDet in (ord.OrderDetails.Where(od => od.BackOrdered == true) ?? Enumerable.Empty<OrderDetail>()).DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where cust != null && (null != ord) && (null != ordDet)
                 select ordDet
               ).Count();

            int linqyTotalBackOrderedCountTwo =
                   (
                     from cust in customers
                     from ord in (cust.Orders ?? Enumerable.Empty<Order>()).DefaultIfEmpty()
                     from ordDet in (ord.OrderDetails.Where(od => od.BackOrdered == true) ?? Enumerable.Empty<OrderDetail>()).DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where cust != null && (null!=cust.Orders) && (null!=ord) && (null!=ord.OrderDetails) && (null!=ordDet)
                     select ordDet
                   ).Count();
```

Is there a "null friendly" way in linq to get children of children ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this without needing to worry about nulls.

```
var count = customers.Where (c => c.Orders != null)
    .SelectMany (c => c.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderDetails != null)
        .SelectMany (o => o.OrderDetails))
    .Count (c => c.BackOrdered);
```

The above was close...here is the final answer:

```
            int itWorksCount = customers.Where(c => null != c && null != c.Orders)
                    .SelectMany(c => c.Orders.Where(o => null != o && null != o.OrderDetails)
                        .SelectMany(o => o.OrderDetails.Where(ordDet => null != ordDet)))
                    .Count(c => c.BackOrdered);
```

Comment: Sorry dude.  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @granadaCoder You are right, it is fixed. Looks like the null checks are required.

Comment: (After the change, not a repeat comment)  ::: Sorry dude. Still getting : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 1):

Do not have `ICollection<T>` properties be `null`. There is absolutely no reason to have `null` values in there, when you can also have an empty collection (which you instantiate in the constructor even, so you are not saving memory).

Redesign your `Customer` and `Order` classes so that the setter of the `Orders`  and `OrderDetails` property is private. Your serialization should be able to handle this (Entity Framework / NHibernate / Data Contracts do at least). This prevents other code from setting the collection to `null`.

Also, why do you allow inserting `null` values into the collections? What does the `null` value represent. Is there an unfilled order, a placeholder for something? If that is the case, put in some value that represents a missing order / order detail.

After fixing your design, use Gary. S's original answer:

```
int count =  customers.SelectMany(c => c.Orders)
                      .SelectMany(o => o.OrderDetails)
                      .Count(od => od.BackOrdered);
```

Note, there is always a null friendly way to do everything, but it makes code overly complex and hard to maintain.

Comment: It's legacy code dude.......Obviously not having nulls is the ideal situation...but it isn't always available.   I edited Gary's code....and now it works......with all the nulls and all.

Comment: @granadaCoder sounds like buggy code if collections get reset to null and null values are inserted into collections. It can be hiding some bigger problem.. Just saying, you can always add null checks for everything, but it's likely hiding the problem.